# Combining multiple columns (Excel) into 1 with associated column of dates

Tags: excel

Reviewed many threads on similar issues, but none addresses my particular challenge.  I have a column (A) of dates (10K+), followed by a column (B) of event hosts, followed by multiple columns (C-X) of co-hosts.  From these, I need to create 2 columns - 1 of dates and 1 combined list of hosts/co-hosts (each associated with their specific date).  In other words, the co-host listings will be inserted into the host list (as a new row) and the appropriate associated date will be generated in the adjacent date column.

Caveats:  (1) there are blank cells (in co-host columns), which need to be ignored; (2) the list will continue to expand each year (+~5K); (3) prefer a formulaic solution, if possible.

Can anyone assist?  Many thanks!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For a formula way of doing this I would add the following formula into column Y

```
=B1
```

And then the following formula into Column Z:

```
=X1 & IF(LEN(C1)>0,", "&C1,"")
```

Then drag that formula across to the right for the 22 or so columns (the number between B and X). The last column should have what you are after, you could then Ctrl-X to a different part of the workbook. I have assumed you would like a column between the names. I hope that helps